# Xcode Instruments - testing a framework?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode-instruments

We've written and non-ARC Objective-C framework and would like to test it for leaks in Instruments. We're used to testing a full app, but are unclear on how we should best test a single framework given it's not an executable target.

How should we approach profiling the framework?

Comment: Did you try the static analyzer? It's pretty smart.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, matt! The static analyzer is exactly what we need. Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Where can I find static analyzer in Xcode 14.2?